How do I evaluate an XSLT expression in isolation using Nokogiri?
We're using an XSLT transform, given to us by a third party, to validate an XML document; it transforms the document into a collection of error nodes, which will be empty if the XML document is valid.  We're using Nokogiri to perform the transform.
One rule in the XSLT document is triggering, even though I don't think it should be.  The expression for the part that's failing reduces to:
date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2023-06-01'),normalize-space('-P3M'))))
=
date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2024-05-31'),normalize-space('-P3M'))))    

which I think should be comparing the year part of 1st March 2023 with the year part of 29th Feb 2024 and finding them to be different, but it's finding them to be the same.
I want to test this expression in isolation, to confirm whether it really is the problem.  I've tried evaluating just one part of it like so:
doc = Nokogiri::XML('')
doc.xpath(
  "date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2023-06-01'),normalize-space('-P3M'))))"
)

but this raises xmlXPathCompOpEval: function add bound to undefined prefix date.
If I try adding the EXSLT namespace like so:
doc.xpath(
  "date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2023-06-01'),normalize-space('-P3M'))))", 
  { "date" => "http://exslt.org/dates-and-times") }
)

...then it raises xmlXPathCompOpEval: function add not found.
What do I need to do to use Nokogiri to evaluate the above expression?

It seems an XPath + EXSLT expression not using a context node so you should be able to evaluate with an XPath API setting the context node to null/empty or whatever that translates to in your environment.

Thanks! Do you know what that would look like with Nokogiri?

No, sorry, only saw the question because of the XSLT tag but I don't use Nokogiri.

Are you able to use an actual XSLT document?

I don't know what XSLT processor you are using, but the chances are that it has access to an implementation of the EXSLT date-and-time library, and since that library is designed for use from XSLT rather than XPath, it's intrinsically unlikely that Nokogiri has access to these functions. In which case the answer to your question is: sorry, this ain't gonna work.

If you can use an actual XSLT document then running this stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2023-06-01'),normalize-space('-P3M'))))
=
date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2024-05-31'),normalize-space('-P3M')))) "/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

against any XML document should give you the result you are looking for - which of course should be:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>false</test>

You could use Nokogiri to do it like so:
  xml = Nokogiri::XML("")

  xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(<<~XSLT)
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    extension-element-prefixes="date">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <test>
            <xsl:value-of select="date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2023-06-01'),normalize-space('-P3M'))))
    =
    date:year(normalize-space(date:add(normalize-space('2024-05-31'),normalize-space('-P3M')))) "/>
        </test>
    </xsl:template>
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
  XSLT
  
  puts xslt.transform(xml).to_s


Thanks!  I think I've worked out how to wrap this in the right Ruby code to drive Nokogiri to do the above.  Would it be OK if I edited your answer to include that, then I'll mark it as accepted?

Sure, go ahead. Or post your own version.

Next time you have a question about XSLT, find out which XSLT processor you are using (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153) and state this in your question.

As a newbie to XSLT, I had thought that "Nokogiri" was the answer to that question.  Next time I'll know better.

It's possible, but unlikely. They are probably using an established library such as libxslt. --- Ah, I should have just looked it up at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokogiri_(software): it is indeed libxslt.
